# How to change the title color of EKEventViewController in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent, ekeventkit

[image]

It is private class called `EKCustomTitleView`. And you cannot imagine the "Event Details" is `UIImageView` instead of `UILabel`.

```
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: myAppLabelColor]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: myAppLabelColor]
```

I try to add this, but it cannot work.